# Are there any differences between a T-800 endoskeleton and a T-800 Infiltrator (besides the living issue)?

Tags: the-terminator-series

Are there any differences between the combat chassis of a [T-800 endoskeleton](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-800#Endoskeleton) and a [T-800 Infiltrator](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/T-800#Infiltration)? In other words, can a T-800 endoskeleton be converted to an Infiltrator by simply adding the living tissue covering, or does the chassis require some modification for the living tissue to fit over it properly?

On one hand, for compatibility purposes it would be beneficial for the combat chassis to be identical between the endoskeleton and Infiltrator versions. On the other hand, the endoskeleton and Infiltrator serve in different combat roles: the endoskeleton is used in open combat and would benefit from increased armor, while the Infiltrator needs to appear as human-like as possible (possibly at the expense of armor).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be. Just going from the films, there isn't much visual difference between a T-800 endoskeleton whether it is wearing flesh, naked, or in rags as a poor attempt to pass as human. They are all hard to kill, requiring crushing in most cases (even the one killed by a close up shot to the head [in T3, IIRC] was pinned in a wrecked vehicle). I'm not sure we have ever seen a T-800 killed strictly by small arms (Reese's flashback in T1, for example, never showed the infiltrator being stopped) though maybe there were some in T4.

Of course there appear to be some differences in the T-800 in various versions across the films (I doubt the T1 version had the nuclear explosive power cells seem in T3 for example)